# Beta coefficients in a panel data random effects regression model

Tags: statistics, stata, random-effects

I wanted to get beta coefficients in my panel data random effects regression model in Stata. But then I noticed that the option "beta" is not allowed in the `xtreg` command.

It made me think if it is probably wrong to want standardised coefficients in a random effects model?

my model looks something like this -

```
xtreg y x##z, re
```

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are seeking here. I would suggest that you edit your post and provide a clearer explanation.

Comment: This question really seems like it's more about the random effects model than about Stata coding. I bet you'd get a more informative answer on stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually get standardized coefficients by 0-1 standardizing your variables before the command:

```
foreach v of varlist x y z {
   qui sum `v'
   replace `v' = (`v'-`r(mean)') / `r(sd)'

xtreg y x##z, re
```